# ToMailMessage() - An invalid character in Header

Tags: c#, openpop

I have got a console application that processes emails in a mailbox using OpenPOP, it is failing on one email with the following exception

```
An invalid character was found in the mail header: '\u007f
```

The code it is calling is the following

```
            MailMessage _testMail = emailFile.ToMailMessage();               
            _testMail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            _testMail.Subject = _testMail.Subject + " Issue ID: " + callid;
```

it is failing when it calls emailFile.ToMailMessage() and help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u007f` is the [`DELETE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7f/index.htm) character - that seems to be invalid in your context. You might have to strip unwanted characters from your input before calling `.ToMailMessage`.